# Google Container Engine Expose Service "Site Cannot Be Reached"

Tags: python, docker, containers, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am looking build a simple web application using Flask, Docker, and Google Container Engine.  I have specified the following DockerFile:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a base image
FROM python:2.7-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8080

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Note I am exposing port 8080.

Here is my simple Flask application:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask import make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

tasks = [
    {
        'type': 'order',
        'contents':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    }
]

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    return jsonify({'tasks': tasks})

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Not found'}), 404)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Note `host='0.0.0.0'` and `port=8080`.

I run the docker container locally, successfully:

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/hello-node:v1
```

However, when I deploy the application using the Google Container Engine I am not able to access the application via the external port provided by `kubectl get service`.

I run the following to deploy a `Pod`:

```
kubectl run hello-world --image=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/hello-node:v1 --port 8080
```

I run the following commands to create a `Service` to access from the internet:

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-world --type=LoadBalancer --port 8080
```

Why am I not able to access the service?  It seems I have opened port 8080 within every step 1) Flask application 2) Dockerfile 3) `Pod` Deployment  4) `Service` creation.

Comment: What's the output of `curl -I -v http://$(kubectl get svc hello-world -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}'):8080`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should point out the target port as well when exposing your deployment, like this:

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-world --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080 --target-port=8080
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Jahongir.  Thank you for this.  I have run the following command `kubectl expose deployment hello-world --type=LoadBalancer --port 8080 --target-port 8080` and am still not able to connect.

Comment: I am not sure whether it makes a difference but you are not putting `=` between `--port` and `8080`. Can you try with `--port=8080 --target-port=8080`?